# How to get real prediction from TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm really new to TensorFlow and MI in general. I've been reading a lot, been searching days, but haven't really found anything useful, so..

My main problem is that every single tutorial/example uses images/words/etc., and the outcome is just a vector with numbers between 0 and 1 (yeah, that's the probability). Like that beginner tutorial, where they want to identify numbers in images. So the result set is just a "map" to every single digit's (0-9) probability (kind of). Here comes my problem: I have no idea what the result could be, it could be 1, 2, 999, anything.

So basically:

```
input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

This really is just a simplified example. I would always have the same number of inputs and outputs, but how can I get the predicted values back with TensorFlow, not just something like `[0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]`? I'm not really sure how clear my question is, if it's not, please ask.

Comment: I don't know your programming background or TensorFlow as a framework, but is there something stopping you from writing a threshold function that takes a decision rule and applies it to each of the probabilities? If that's not something in your background, you're probably best served by boning up on detection theory and visiting CrossValidated.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Is your output a label that stands for a certain class, like e.g. 0-9 stands for the respective digits, or is your output a real-valued variable?

Comment: @kaufmanu My output would be a real-valued variable. I just can't find a single example/tutorial that is showing me how to do that.

Comment: It seems then that you are trying to solve a regression problem, not a classification problem like e.g. detecting whether an image shows digit 0, 1, ..., 9. If you google for `tensorflow regression tutorial` I am sure something will come up, e.g. this link: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples

Comment: @kaufmanu Thanks, will take a look!